# TypeError cv2.rect

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection-api, openvino

Am trying to implement an object detection model on an image using **ssd_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28** model.
 Am trying to get the output with a bounding box on top.

1) ssd_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28 object detection model. Successfully converted to IR.

2) Taken an input image and preprocessed it according to the input layer information of the model.

3) Successfully extracted the model outputs.

4) Added bounding boxes to the output image.

But am getting the following error, please help!

**Source Code**

```
#Preprocessing image

img = r'D:\SriSailam.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(img)
img = cv2.resize(img,(300,300))
img = img.transpose((2,0,1))
img = img.reshape(1,3,300,300)



exec_net = engine.load_network(net,'cpu')


#Asynchronous request

infer_request_handle = exec_net.start_async(request_id=0, inputs={'image_tensor': img}) 
infer_status = infer_request_handle.wait()
output = next(iter(net.outputs))


n,c,h,w = img.shape

result = infer_request_handle.outputs[output]  #output layer shape


'''
Draw bounding boxes onto the image.
'''
for box in result[0][0]: # Output shape is 1x1x100x7
        conf = box[2]  #box[2] = result[0][0][2] is a probability value
        print("probability value : ",conf)
        print("box[0] : ",box[0])
        print("box[1] : ",box[1])
        print("xmin : ", box[3])
        print("ymin : ", box[4])
        print("xmax : ", box[5])
        print("ymax : ", box[6])

        if conf >= 0:
            xmin = int(box[3] * w)  #box[3] - xmin
            ymin = int(box[4] * h) #box[4] - ymin
            xmax = int(box[5] * w)  #box[5] - xmax
            ymax = int(box[6] * h) #box[6] - ymax
            rect = cv2.rectangle(img, ((xmin), (ymin)), ((xmax), (ymax)), (0, 0, 255), 1)
cv2.imshow(rect,'face_detection')
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Output**

```
C:\Users\adity\Desktop\openvino>py check_infer.py                                                                                                                        
probability value :  0.6344592                                                                                                                                           
box[0] :  0.0                                                                                                                                                            
box[1] :  1.0                                                                                                                                                            
xmin :  0.1831626                                                                                                                                                        
ymin :  0.10697469                                                                                                                                                       
xmax :  0.86960804                                                                                                                                                       
ymax :  1.0                                                                                                                                                              
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                       
  File "check_infer.py", line 68, in <module>                                                                                                                            
    rect = cv2.rectangle(img, ((xmin), (ymin)), ((xmax), (ymax)), (0, 0, 255), 1)                                                                                        
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

Comment: Which opencv version? Did you try with `cv2.rectangle(img, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), (0, 0, 255), 1)`?

Comment: version is 4.2.0 . And i tried with same function u specified.

Comment: I removed the extra parenthesis around `xmin`, `ymin`, `xmax`, and `ymax` in my call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproduced your error.
The error message is pretty confusing in this version of OpenCV (4.2.0).

If you do the same in OpenCV 4.3.0 you will get a more intelligible error like

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'
```

Which basically says that `img` argument you passed into `cv2.rectangle` has a wrong type.
The problem is that after you call

```
img = img.transpose((2,0,1))
img = img.reshape(1,3,300,300)
```

`img` cannot be interpreted as an image by OpenCV.
The issue can be solved, for example, this way:
1. Copy `img` before the transformation to another variable `imgForDisplaying`
2. Use `imgForDisplaying` to draw rectangle.

```
img = r'D:\SriSailam.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(img)
img = cv2.resize(img,(300,300))
imgToDisplay = img
img = img.transpose((2,0,1))
img = img.reshape(1,3,300,300)
...
rect = cv2.rectangle(imgToDisplay, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), (0, 0, 255), 1)
```

Comment: hey Artemy, i can't thank you enough for this, it works like a charm. But there's another issue which has raised, i hope you you can fix this,

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                       
  File "check_infer.py", line 70, in <module>                                                                                                                            
    cv2.imshow(rect,'face_detection')                                                                                                                                    
SystemError: <built-in function imshow> returned NULL without setting an error

Comment: Ok never mind, fixed it!!!!
Artemy again, a hugeee thankss to you. You literally made my day!!!!

Comment: That's great! :) I am glad that could help.